# Formik Validation Schema preventing onSubmit method to be called

Tags: javascript, typescript, formik, yup

It's my first time using Formik and I'm trying to use it to validate a user registration form. Here is my code:

```
interface Props { }

export interface RegisterData {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    status?: boolean
}

const validationSchema: SchemaOf<RegisterData> = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup
        .string()
        .max(20, "Name cannot be more than 20 characters")
        .required("name is required"),
    email: yup
        .string()
        .email("Enter a valid email")
        .required("Email is required"),
    password: yup
        .string()
        .min(8, "Password should be of minimum 8 characters")
        .required("Password is required"),
    status: yup
        .boolean()
        .notRequired()
});

const Create: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const initialFormValues: RegisterData = {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }

    const handleChecked = (event: any) => {
        console.log(event.target.checked);
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(values);
        
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: initialFormValues,
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
        onSubmit: handleSubmit
    })

    return (
        <Box
            ...
                <Box component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <Typography
                                variant="subtitle1"
                                sx={{
                                    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
                                }}
                            >
                                {Constants.Create.NAME_HEADER}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="name"
                                name="name"
                                label="Required"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                sx={{
                                    marginTop: "0px"
                                }}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <Typography
                                variant="subtitle1"
                                sx={{
                                    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
                                }}
                            >
                                {Constants.Create.EMAIL_HEADER}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="email"
                                name="email"
                                label="Required"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                sx={{
                                    marginTop: "0px"
                                }}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <Typography
                                variant="subtitle1"
                                sx={{
                                    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
                                }}
                            >
                                {Constants.Create.PASSWORD_HEADER}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                type="password"
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="password"
                                name="password"
                                label="Required"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                sx={{
                                    marginTop: "0px"
                                }}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        size="large"
                        sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 2 }}
                    >
                        {Constants.Create.CREATE_ACCOUNT}
                    </Button>
                </Box>
        </Box >
    )
}
```

When I click on my submit button and handleSubmit is called, nothing happens and I dont see `hello` or `values` being printed to the console. However when I remove `validationSchema` from `useFormik`, I can get the outputs.

Why is this happening? How can I add the `schemaValidation` to Formik?

Comment: Don't know much about the situation but never write empty interfaces. That's unrelated but you need to know it. TS is structural.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem could be that you are not controlling the state of your fields. When you click the submit button nothing happens because the input elements are updated with uncontrolled values.

The solution is to add on each field the `value` and the `onChange` attributes pointing to the formik `values` state and the `handleChange` method.

You can also add the `disabled` attribute to the button passing to it `disabled={formik.isValid || formik.isSubmitting}` to have a dynamic view of the state of the form. Here more infos about formik APIs https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeeventany--void

Example:

```
<TextField
     value={formik.values.password}
     onChange={formik.handleChange}
     ...your other props
 />
```

In addition, just for suggestion, put outside the function component body the `initialFormValues` object, you don't need to recreate it at every re-render.